# How do I center elements in a Flexbox column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a one pager HTML site. I am trying to center the content in the middle vertically (so that the image, the text below it and the two buttons are moving a little bit more down) on this website: https://werwichtelt.de

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `main` element

```
main {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: It’s perfectly working on desktop. But now the main area is not completely shown on mobile, since it’s try to fit on one screen and overlapped by the footer. I just want the header, main area centered, bottom area. If it’s fitting on the screen, perfect, if not, scroll

Answer (score 0):

may this will work

```
main {
    display: flex;
    jutify-content:center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, this puts the footer up